# Writing in vector form the set of solutions giving a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Write in vector form the set of solutions to the homogeneous system of linear equations with matrix $A$, defined by:

\begin{bmatrix}
0& 0\\
0& 0\\
\end{bmatrix}

This is a $2 \times 2$ matrix which has all entries are zero.

$A$ is the homogeneous system that is given to us. It is also a $2 \times 2$ matrix which has all entries equal to zero). But, I did not understand this question.

Comment: So $A$ is the $2\times 2$ zero matrix and you want the solutions to the homogeneous system $Ax=0$?

Comment: yes. I guess it ..

Comment: Well what vectors $x$ can you multiply by the zero matrix to get the zero vector?

Comment: All vectors ? The answer is R ?

Comment: Well yeah it's all vectors, but that's not $\mathbb R$. If your ground field is $\mathbb R$, then it would be all vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ that solve $Ax=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the system $$\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)x=\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)$$ the solution is $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: why the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want the intuitive answer (as in the comments).

Clearly, the domain of this linear mapping is in the $R^2$ space. Since the rank of this matrix is 0, the null space is also dimension 2 which spans the entire same $R^2$ vector space.